# Microphone has about one minute dictation limit on iPad Air 2

Tags: ios, microphone, voice-dictation, ipad

My iPad microphone cuts out after about one minute of dictation. I've tried using Google and Word but the same limitations apply. Does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it on my iPhone and I didn't get the dictation longer than one minute to work either. I don't know if it's a bug or a "feature", but I would assume it is limited by iOS.